# Sort numpy arrays from .dat files in the right row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a question about storing data from .dat files in the right row of a dataframe. I go with this minimal example.

I have already a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4],'col2': ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['row_exp1','row_exp2','row_exp3','row_exp4'])
```

Now I want to add a new column called `col3` with numpy arrays in each single cell. Thus, I will have 4 numpy arrays, one in every cell.

I get the numpy arrays from a `.dat` file.

The import part is that I have to found the *right* row. I have **4** `.dat` files and every dat file matches to the row name. For example the first `.dat` file has got the name *230109_exp3_foo.dat*. So this dat file matches to the third row of my dataframe.

Then the algorithm has to put the data from the .dat file in the right cell:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row_exp1 | 1 | a |  |
| row_exp2 | 2 | b |  |
| row_exp3 | 3 | c | [1,2,3,4,5,6] |
| row_exp4 | 4 | d |  |

The other entries should be NaN and I would fill them with the right numpy array in the next loop.

I think the difficult part is to select the right row and to math this with the file name of the .dat file.

Comment: pandas dataframes aren't really designed to have collections as values. they can of course, but it's a bit of an anti-pattern. why do you want to do this instead of adding new columns for each value?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I want to do this, since I have time series as data with more than 200000 single points. So I get this from my experiment and I want to store the time series in the right row for each operation point.

Comment: If you’re dealing with that much data, you definitely want a “tidy” data frame that has scalars as values and categorical columns to label each observation appropriately

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean, since it sounds interesting and could help me to work easier with my large amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with time series data, this isn't how you want to structure your dataframe. Read up on "tidy" data. (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Every column is a variable. Every row is an observation.

So let's assume you're loading your data with a function called `load_data` that accepts a file name:

```py
def load_data(filename):
    # load the data, fill in your own details
    pass
```

Then you would build up your dataframe like this:

```py
meta_data = {
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'col2': ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
}
list_of_dataframes = []
for n, fname in enumerate(filenames):
    this_array = load_data(fname)
    list_of_dataframes.append(
        pd.DataFrame({
            'row_num': list(range(len(this_array))),
            'col1': meta_data['col1'][n],
            'col2': meta_data['col2'][n],
            'values': this_array,
        })
    )

df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps:

```
# Do you have the similar pattern in each .dat file name? (I assume that yes)
list_of_files = ['230109_exp3_foo.dat', '230109_exp2_foo.dat', '230109_exp1_foo.dat', '230109_exp4_foo.dat']
# for each index trying to find value after row_ in file list
files_match = df.reset_index()['index'].map(lambda x: [y for y in list_of_files if x.replace('row_', '') in y])
# if I understand correctly, you know how to read .dat file, 
# so you can insert your function instead of function_for_reading_dat_file
df['col3'] = files_match.map(lambda x: function_for_reading_dat_file(x[0]) if len(x) != 0 else 'None')
```